# Best practice for Decorator design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

In the right place Decorator design pattern shines, but i noticed in many applications few mistakes made while using decorator.

an exemple (using `java.io`) which demonstrate the problem with bad using of Decorator.

```
public OutputStream foo(...){
    return new BufferedOutputStream(...);
}
```

The problem with this method, it return a `BufferedOutputStream` as `OutputStream`, so a user may decorate again this object by `BufferedOutputStream` (he don't know that the method return a buffered stream), so here we got double buffering for free (worsing more the performance for nothing).

another exemple :

```
public void foo(OutputStream os){
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(is);
    ...
}
```

Here another exemple, the user may supply `BufferedOutputStream` to foo which already decorate it for internal use, the user may want to increase performance by providing a buffered stream, but in reality he's making it more worse, its not his fault, he don't know what the method do inside (Black box).

So anyone can tell me what is the best practices for using Decorator design pattern, not only with `java.io` but with general use for Decorator?

Comment: The problem here is not in decorators conception but in a missing documentation. In a first example, you can make return type BufferedOutputStream explicitly. In second method instanceof check can prevent from double buffering, if it is important.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker yes that is, but i'm looking for general advices when using/writting decorators, also documentation shouldn't describe internals, it just describe the behavoir, for exemple, does XML API buffers InputStream? i don't know, and its not written in a documentation :)

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill Unfortunately you cannot. The decorator pattern does not dictate any decoration chain formally. This is the key point: you're still working with the most basic type, `OutputStream` (but not `BufferedOutputStream`) `List` (but not an `unmodifiableList(...)` instance) whatever, because you probably don't care the most concrete type as long as you're working with abstractions. You could create a special decorator with a special `List<SuperType> getChain()` method, but I doubt you would ever formally check this chain.